# Installing awscli on Alpine - how to fix "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'"

Tags: python, aws-cli, alpine-linux

**Context**

I had a dockerfile based on `postgres:11-alpine` that was working in the past (probably a few months since it was last built) with the following definition:

```
FROM postgres:11-alpine

RUN apk update

# install aws cli
# taken from: https://github.com/anigeo/docker-awscli/blob/master/Dockerfile
RUN \
    apk -Uuv add groff less python py-pip && \
    pip install awscli && \
    apk --purge -v del py-pip && \
    rm /var/cache/apk/*
```

I recently tried to rebuild it before upgrading to postgres 12, but the image build failed with:

```
 ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
              python (missing):
                required by: world[python]
```

I guess the `python` package is gone now because YOLO? Whatever, I tried to upgrade to `python3` by changing the docker file to:

```
RUN \
    apk -Uuv add groff less python3 py-pip && \
    pip install awscli && \
    apk --purge -v del py-pip && \
    rm /var/cache/apk/*
```

This looked like it worked, but then when running the `aws` command it failed with error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'
```

---

**Question**

How to fix this so the `awscli` will not give the error `No module named 'six'`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem seems to actually be caused by deleting `py-pip`.
As far as I know, the aim of the `apk del` was to reduce the size of the final docker image.  I'm not sure why deleting `py-pip` used to work when the file was using the `python` package.

So the following now seems to be working:

```
RUN \
    apk -Uuv add groff less python3 py-pip && \
    pip install awscli && \
    rm /var/cache/apk/*
```